# Como imprimir datos en formato JSON de una array guardado en una función en lenguaje RUBY?

Tags: funciones, ruby, revisión-de-código, jsonarray

Esto es lo que quiero replicar, pero en lenguaje ruby, ya he buscado por todas partes, pero no se como hacerlo

```
php
if ($api->httpcode == 201) {
    $value = json_decode($json, true);
    printf("<br></br>" . $json);
    echo "Create Succesful!";
} else {
    printf("ERROR: HTTPCODE=%d %s", $api->httpcode, $json);
}
?>
```

Comment: hola amiga acabo de agregarte una respuesta y editar tu pregunta un poco. bienvenida a stackoverflow tambien te recomiendo que te leas este articulo: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask Saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Debes implementar:**

```
parsed_json = ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(your_json_string)
```

**Solución:**

```
parsed_json["results"].each do |longUrl, convertedUrl|
  site = Site.find_by_long_url(longUrl)
  site.short_url = convertedUrl["shortUrl"]
  site.save
end
```

no puedo darte una respuesta mas exacta por que no colocaste ni una pieza de código ruby que tengas para adaptarla a lo que tienes; pero del php al ruby esto es lo que puedo aportarte.

[Link de referencia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1826727/how-do-i-parse-json-with-ruby-on-rails)

También existe otra referencia dependiendo de la version que estés usando: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5410713/4717133)

Comment: puts  "Create company"
  
 def create_company(company_name: "Jedrade Industries",
                     address1: "10 Vantage Point Drive" ,
                     address2: "Ste. 1",
                     city: "Rochester",
                     state:"NY",
                     zip_code: "14624",
                     company_phone: "123-456-7890",
                     e_mail: "Ejemplo@hotmail.com",
                     full_name: "Example")

    post('Company', args_to_hash(__method__, binding)) . to_json
  end     este es el codigo ruby de ejemplp

Comment: @AbigailCaton hola te recomiendo que uses ese código en tu propio post en los comentarios ese tipo de código no es legible.